# Get table value without a model in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core

I've got an application that migrated to Entity Framework Core. But I have some apps which need to support this migration. They have a column in their table that doesn't exist anymore (it lives in another place).

I'm trying to figure out how I can use my Entity Framework Core application to read the old database and extract the column information if it exists.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To make this less broad.

I have a table in an old sqlite database that has a column. I'd like to extract that column from the old database using Entity Framework Core in order to insert it into the new location.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own sql code instead of using Entity Framework abstraction.

I personaly use something which I found on the web (can't find the original source anymore) to add generic class support linked to my custom query:

```
public class MyRefDatabaseContext: RefDatabaseContext
{
    public List<T> ExecSQL<T>(string query)
    {
        using (var command = Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Database.OpenConnection();

            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                T obj = default(T);
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (!object.Equals(result[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(obj, result[prop.Name], null);
                        }
                    }
                    list.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            Database.CloseConnection();
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I added wrapping class for clarity

Comment: This looks like ADO.Net not EF Core.

Comment: well the code I put in my answer is right now working in production in a .net core environment with Entity Framework. I will delete the link as I am less sure that this answer the question.